# Problems clearing a linked list, seg faulting delete

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
  LinkedList* p = this;
  LinkedList* q = this;
  while(p->m_next != NULL)
  {
    p = p->m_next;
    delete q;
    q = p;
  }
  return;
}

class LinkedList
{
public:
  T m_data;                  // Data to be stored
  LinkedList<T>* m_next;     // Pointer to the next element in the list
 //Continues into function declarations.
 // . . .
};
```

These are the snippets of code I thought relevant, if you need any more let me know.

The problem: I am seg faulting once I hit the line to delete q

```
delete q;
```

I plugged in some

```
cerr << "msg" << endl;
```

Just to check. Any ideas of how to alter this code to stop the seg fault? Apparently I'm deleting something I shouldn't be, but I can't figure out how. The point of the clear function is to entirely delete the singly linked list except for the ending sentinel. This while loop always seg faults on the first run.

Here is the code testing this.

```
void test01() {

  LinkedList < int > A;

  cout << endl << endl; 
  cout << " ***************** " << endl;
  cout << " *  TEST SET #1  * " << endl;
  cout << " ***************** " << endl;


  cout << "Is the list empty? " << boolalpha << A.isEmpty() <<endl; 
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl;

  //TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to a
  cout << endl << "TEST : Inserting 10 numbers to A" << endl;
  for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
        A.insert_front(k+1);
  } 
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of a = " << A.size() << endl;

  //TEST : Clearing A
  cout << endl << "TEST : Clearing A" << endl;
  A.clear();
  cout << A << endl;
  cout << "Size of A = " << A.size() << endl << endl;


  cout << "Test 01 - Done!" << endl;
} // Destructor Called Here!!
```

I simply changed the function to

```
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear()
{
  LinkedList* p = this;
  LinkedList* q = this;
  if(p->m_next != NULL)
  {
    p = p->m_next;
    q = q->m_next;
  }
  while(p->m_next != NULL)
  {
    q = p;
    p = p->m_next;
    delete q;
  }
  m_next = NULL;
  return;
}
```

Works now.

Comment: umm, your deleting yourself

Comment: @RobGoodwin that's not a problem in itself.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: No, but 99.99999999999999% it directly leads to a serious one.

Comment: The problem isn't here, it's in the code that uses this code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I think there's a serious design smell right here. Of course, that's pretty much always the case when `std::list` gets NIH'd.

Comment: I provided the code testing this, I'm still rather clueless. Also, I realize c++ has this class in it, but I was assigned to write it.

Comment: it would be easier for everyone if you posted the whole code, and just don't worry much about those who like to make a fuss just cause your not a C++ artist (yet anyway)

Comment: Uh, the reason it works now that you've changed it is because it doesn't do anything. You skip to where `p->m_next == NULL` and then do that again in a second loop which exits immediately. Like I said, you shouldn't be using `delete` on automatic objects.

Comment: Actually, it does do something. I completely clears the list now, as was the original intent. Also, the only reason delete wasn't working originally is because I was trying to keep the sentinel and not the calling object and was thus trying to delete the calling object.

Comment: Oops, misread the `if` as `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're allocating the `LinkedList` in automatic storage but using `delete` on it. That's UB.

However, the design you've chosen engenders other errors, even though I've only pointed out the one that directly relates to your segfault. Most linked lists are designed as classes that manages lists of nodes, and they don't expose the node class to the client. I would suggest you follow that method.

Comment: I was provided the .h and had to work on it from there... thanks!